How to read a csv into pandas with missing columns in the header?
I have a CSV file from a measurement device, that produces a bunch of values (Temperature, Rain and Wind) and gives some metadata for the device:
Station, Hillside
ID, 12345
elevation, 54321
units, °C, mm, kph
time, temp, prec, wind
2024-08-01 00:00, 18, 0, 5
2024-08-01 01:00, 18, 0, 2
2024-08-01 02:00, 17.5, 3, 14

When I try to read this with df=pd.read_csv('12345.csv', header=[0,1,2,3,4], index_col=0, parse_dates=True) I get an Header rows must have an equal number of columns error. If I read it in with header=[3,4], where I have all columns, it works, but especially the Station name would be rather important to have.
I can probably read that in separately and then add it to the df's multiindex, but I wonder if I'm missing some obvious shortcut, since a lot of devices that produce csv files appear to add the metadata on top, without filling out all columns. Especially since I can have multiindex rows, that stretch over many columns.
Edit: Essentially, I'm looking for a dataframe like this:
Station             Hillside                |m i
ID                  12345                   |u n
elevation           54321                   |l d
units               °C      mm   kph        |t e
time                temp    prec wind       |i x
__________________________________________
2024-08-01 00:00:00 18.0    0    5          |d
2024-08-01 01:00:00 18.0    0    2          |a 
2024-08-01 02:00:00 17.5    3    14         |t
...                                         |a      


How do you want to add the metadata? E.g., do you want to add a column Station with value Hillside and so on. Do your files always have the same amount of rows for this metadata, and is each row always a "pair" like in this example?

Metadata should be large-ish multiindex on top (~.columns). Files should all be the same.

Do you really want to include the metadata as MultiIndex? I suggest to load the metadata into the attribution of the DataFrame (df.attrs). The advantages are:


you have the classical access to the column without the overhead of MultiIndex, e.g.: (df['time'] vs. df['Station', 'ID', 'Elevation', 'Units', 'Time'] or df['temp'] vs. df['Hillside', ' 12345', '54321', '°C', 'temp']).


the metadata is directly accessible from the attributes instead of extracting the metadata from the MulitIndex.




When writing the file back to csv, you can write the header first and then use pandas to write the table.


You can read all rows specifying names in read_csv, then create a MultiIndex with the first rows and slice the dataframe with iloc:
cols_height = 4
cols_width = 5

df = pd.read_csv('12345.csv', names=range(cols_height))
df = (
    df.iloc[cols_width:]
    .set_axis(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
            df.iloc[:cols_width].fillna("").T, names=[None] * cols_width
        ),
        axis=1,
    )
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(df)

            Station  Hillside            
                 ID     12345            
          elevation     54321            
              units        °C    mm   kph
               time      temp  prec  wind
0  2024-08-01 00:00        18     0     5
1  2024-08-01 01:00        18     0     2
2  2024-08-01 02:00      17.5     3    14

print(df.columns)

MultiIndex([(  'Station',     'ID', 'elevation', 'units',  'time'),
            (' Hillside', ' 12345',    ' 54321',   ' °C', ' temp'),
            (         '',       '',          '',   ' mm', ' prec'),
            (         '',       '',          '',  ' kph', ' wind')],
           )


You can parse the metadata "by hand" (via pure Python) and leave the rest of the file for pandas to consume. Then combine information:
from io import StringIO
from textwrap import dedent
import pandas as pd

buffer = StringIO(dedent('''
    Station, Hillside
    ID, 12345
    elevation, 54321
    units, °C, mm, kph
    time, temp, prec, wind
    2024-08-01 00:00, 18, 0, 5
    2024-08-01 01:00, 18, 0, 2
    2024-08-01 02:00, 17.5, 3, 14
''').strip())

# only parse and clean the metadata
metadata = []
for line in buffer:
    row = [value.strip() for value in line.split(',')]
    metadata.append(row)
    if row[0] == 'units':
        break

# let pandas handle the rest of the file
df = pd.read_csv(buffer)

# reassemble metadata
index_values = [
    row if len(row) == len(df.columns) else [row[0], *([row[1]] * (len(df.columns)-1))]
    for row in metadata
]

# the dataframe columns is the last "row" of metadata
index_values.append(df.columns.tolist())

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index_values)
df.columns = index # or df.set_axis(index, axis=1)
print(df)
#             Station Hillside
#                  ID    12345
#           elevation    54321
#               units       °C    mm   kph
#                time     temp  prec  wind
# 0  2024-08-01 00:00     18.0     0     5
# 1  2024-08-01 01:00     18.0     0     2
# 2  2024-08-01 02:00     17.5     3    14


Use names instead of header
df = pd.read_csv('12345.csv', names=[0,1,2,3,4], index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

Output
                          1      2      3   4
0                                            
Station            Hillside    NaN    NaN NaN
ID                    12345    NaN    NaN NaN
elevation             54321    NaN    NaN NaN
units                    °C     mm    kph NaN
time                   temp   prec   wind NaN
2024-08-01 00:00         18      0      5 NaN
2024-08-01 01:00         18      0      2 NaN
2024-08-01 02:00       17.5      3     14 NaN


Yes, I can read it like that, but now I have to turn the top few rows into a multiindex, turn the first column into an index and repair the data types.

@JC_CL what are your expected results?

I've edited in a representation of the expected df. I have lots of df's like this, but they've all been made by hand. so it's odd to me, that read_csv apparently can't deal with it.

@JC_CL I don't think it's odd at all, CSVs are supposed to be a straightforward format.
